# How do I update a SPFx App in Dev without updating Staging or Prod?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, app-catalog

Ok, I did a change in one of my SPFx web parts, incremented the version in `package-solution.json` file and deployed the app in the app catalog.

In the Dev site I went into the Details for the app, and I saw the new version there and clicked in the Get It button.

I went in the page where the web part is and refreshed the page and it was updated successfully.

However, for my surprise, I went in the production site (in the same tenant) and refreshed the page and the changes were there as well! It was strange because I didn't go to the Details and clicked in the Get it button in the production site.

How can I have different versions of the same web part in Dev/Staging/Prod?

Comment: If you are using a same teanat for all sites then you should consider using site collection level App catalog for such requirements.

Comment: What app catalog are you mentioning here? The **site app catalog** or the **tenant app catalog**? If you upload something to tenant app catalog, it would reflect on all sites. So in your case, you must be using site app catalog like @GaneshSanap mentioned.

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't know there was a site app catalog, only tenant app catalog

Comment: You could configure site collection level app catalog by Add-SPOSiteCollectionAppCatalog as https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a same tenant for development, staging sites and production then it is not possible to update a SPFx App in Development environment without updating Staging or Production.

For such scenarios you should consider using **Site collection level App catalog**.

To configure Site collection level App catalog, check below official documentation by Microsoft:

[Use the site collection app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog)